# Must entangled particles be connected by some means to stay entangles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

The people on this site are far more knowledgeable than I am and I probably don't belong here but my questions always seem to get answered to my satisfaction and I end up learning something. I have been reading  Quantum Entanglement news on www.physics.org and am very perplexed on the actual equipment used for remote experimentation.  Everyone is always hush hush in the reports. I assume the equipment is connected by fiber optic from location to the other?  Does this mean the two entangled states or "particles" are in some sort of actual physical contact with some object that is physically connected to some other object that eventually connects the second "state". If they are separated far enough and both measurements are done close enough in time with synchronized clocks I assume that would exclude any possibility of a hidden signal causing the results on the opposite ends. And I guess this is where my real question comes in.  What is it that is connected? The equipment creating the "states".  The "states" themselves in the form of energy in the cable? or some part of the mechanism that gets to force the fuzzy state into an actual and definite property? Obviously an actual physical connection must exist.? No? I would love to see a schematic of the actual working equipment.

Comment: Entangled sub-systems are not connected, they are merely correlated. Let's say I make two envelopes, one with a green gift card and one with a red one. I send one to my uncle and the other one to my aunt, but I forgot which one has which color. When uncle opens his envelope and finds a green card, does that mean that aunty's card has spontaneously changed to red? Of course not. It only means that uncle's knowledge about aunt's chances of finding a red card have changed from 50% to 100%. Before he opens his, he can't tell what aunty will find, but after he looks at his, he also knows hers.

Comment: No one is being "hush-hush". The papers they write contain enough detail for other researchers to know what they've done. They are a little dense to, say, me because I have only a passing familiarity with the kit that is used for those measurements. Even then I can venture a pretty good guess most of the time and could definitely figure it out by tracking a few of their basic references backward and reading some older papers too. But they are *not* writing for a lay audience, that would be an enormous waste of time. And the pop-sci sources tell you what they think you can digest.

Comment: @CuriousOne answer accepted.   If entangled systems are not connected how does the entangled pair get to a far enough location to exclude a faster then light  signal to its entangled "twin". ? I will have to read more articles and see if I can get at least a description of how the experiment is set up.

Comment: As to the equipment... most of this is done with pretty standard optical benches, stock lasers, beam splitters etc.. Unfortunately, as far as I have seen, there is no real magic sauce here. As with most "direct" experiments the error bars are atrocious and so far I have not seen a smart way of measuring entanglement that could give us a serious experimental test. Having said that, entanglement is a direct consequence of the structure of quantum mechanics. I can not imagine that one can change that structure and not impact most of atomic and molecular spectroscopy.